# Really lost FaceBook password

Tags: facebook, account-management, passwords

Help, please, a friend, and client of mine cannot afford to lose her FB account. The password she created does not work, she has no "Trusted Contacts" to use to regain access and repeated attempts to reset the password through FB do not generate a reply, neither text nor email. We suspect a hack, but there are no posts to make it obvious. I have tried resetting the password it for her myself and we never get a reply from FB. She still has access to FB from her phone, but if she ever loses that phone or when she upgrades, she will have no recourse. Are there social media marketers for hire with actual live connections to humans at FB? I have followed every action possible, including looking at stored passwords on her IPhone settings. Nada. How she still has access from her phone I cannot understand, but I guess the FB app has it encrypted somewhere. Apparently, nowhere we can see.

Answer (score 1):

Does she still have access to the email ID associated with this Facebook account?

If yes:

1. Click on forgot password and follow the link/instructions you receive on that email
2. If you're logged in but have forgotten your password, follow the steps under Change Your Password then click Forgot your password? and follow the steps to reset it. Keep in mind that you'll need access to the email associated with your account. (Taken from https://www.facebook.com/help/213395615347144) - This one will work since you say she is logged in on her phone.

If she does not have access to the email ID then you can try changing the email ID associated with the account from the app where she is logged in.

Comment: Thank you- she does, but the email never arrives. I have tried both procedures you describe. In order to make changes the app asks for a password - not for posts, but for security changes.

Comment: Did you check the spam and promotion folders in her mail box? 
And what email address does it show inside the account section in the Facebook app? 

Also is her phone number connected to her Facebook account?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it turns out FB was just blowing us off. (fix below message from FB) This was their one and only response after several attempts over several weeks (before and after sept 21) . Of course we found this today in a spam folder.
From: Facebook case++aazqzixg46dbjb@support.facebook.com
Sent: Monday, September 21, 2020 11:02 AM
To: G****l N****m <******@******.com>
Subject: We can’t review your ID right now

Hi S******,

We have fewer people available to review IDs due to the coronavirus (COVID-19) outbreak.

We’re only able to review IDs for the most urgent cases. This means we can’t review your ID right now. Please try again at a later date. Thank you for understanding.

The Facebook Team

---

The way we fixed this was as follows: FB was still logged in, in her phone. Although we could not add an email address without being prompted for a password, nor change her phone number, we were able to add a second phone number without being asked for one. Why?- no clue. Once we added her husbands number, we used it successfully as a recovery number to receive a code. Why her own cellphone could not receive a recovery codes from FB? No clue. How you get on FaceBooks "Urgent List"? No clue. So many questions unanswered. Still, we are back in business, which is what matters the most. Thank you Harsh for your help. Truly appreciated.